# Why should different initial points lead to different results for lasso optimization (which is convex)?

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, linear-regression, lasso-regression

I am trying to use lasso optimization on the data with 950 samples and about 5000 features. The lasso function is $(1 / (2 * numberofsamples)) * ||y - Xw||^2_2 + alpha * ||w||_1$.Once I try the minimization with an initialization, I get the totally different w which is odd because lasso is convex and initialization should not affect the result. Here is the result of the lasso with and without initialization. tol is the tolerance. If the change of the w became bellow tolerance, the convergence has happened.

```
tol=0.00000001 
#####  lasso model errors  ##### 


gene: 5478 matrix error: 0.069611732213 
with initialization: alpha: 1e-20 promotion: -3.58847815733e-13 
coef: [-0.00214732 -0.00509795  0.00272167 -0.00651548 -0.00164646 -0.00115342 
  0.00553346  0.01047653  0.00139832] 
without initialization: alpha: 1e-20  promotion: -19.0735249749 
coef: [-0.03650629  0.08992003 -0.01287155  0.03203973  0.1567577  -0.03708655 
-0.13710957 -0.01252736 -0.21710334] 


with initialization: alpha: 1e-15 promotion: 1.06179081478e-10 
coef: [-0.00214732 -0.00509795  0.00272167 -0.00651548 -0.00164646 -0.00115342 
  0.00553346  0.01047653  0.00139832] 
without initialization: alpha: 1e-15  promotion: -19.0735249463 
coef: [-0.03650629  0.08992003 -0.01287155  0.03203973  0.1567577  -0.03708655 
-0.13710957 -0.01252736 -0.21710334] 



Warning (from warnings module): 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py", line 491 
    ConvergenceWarning) 
ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations. Fitting data with very small alpha may cause precision problems. 
with initialization: alpha: 1e-10  promotion: 0.775144987537 
coef: [-0.00185139 -0.0048819   0.00218349 -0.00622618 -0.00145647 -0.00115857 
  0.0055919   0.01072924  0.00043773] 
without initialization: alpha: 1e-10 promotion: -17.8649603301 
coef: [-0.03581581  0.0892119  -0.01232829  0.03151441  0.15606195 -0.03734093 
-0.13604286 -0.01247732 -0.21233529] 


with initialization: alpha: 1e-08 promotion: -5.87121366314 
coef: [-0.          0.         -0.         -0.01064477  0.         -0.00116167 
-0.          0.01114746  0.        ] 
without initialization: alpha: 1e-08  promotion: 4.05593555389 
coef: [ 0.          0.04505117  0.00668611  0.          0.07731668 -0.03537848 
-0.03151995  0.         -0.00310122] 


max promote: 
4.05593555389
```

For the implementation, I used the lasso function of the python package sklearn.linear_model. I also change the data, but the results on the new data alter with initialization too.  I think this is odd but I could not analyze it and find the explanation.

Here is the part of my code, which is related to the lasso. my data is gene expression. I test the code on both normalized and un-normalized data. On both of them the initial point made difference.

```
    alpha_lasso = [1e-20,1e-15, 1e-10, 1e-8, 1e-7,1e-6,1e-5,1e-4, 1e-3,1e-2, 1, 5 ,20]

    lassoreg = Lasso(alpha=alpha_lasso[i],warm_start=True,tol=0.00000001,max_iter=100000)
    lassoreg.coef_ = mybeta[:,j-c]
    lassoreg.fit(train[:,predictors],train[:,y])
    y_train_pred = lassoreg.predict(A)#train[:,predictors])
    y_test_pred = lassoreg.predict(C)#test[:,predictors])
```

Here also is my whole code:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import os
from GEOparse.GEOTypes import (GSE, GSM, GPL, GDS,
                               GDSSubset, GEODatabase,
                               DataIncompatibilityException,
                               NoMetadataException,
                               )
import GEOparse as GEO
import numpy as np
import copy
import sys
import math
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoLars
from sklearn.linear_model import MultiTaskLassoCV
from sklearn.linear_model import coordinate_descent
from sklearn.linear_model import lasso_path, enet_path


import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin
from copy import deepcopy

miss_percent = 0.1
alpha_lasso = [1e-20,1e-15, 1e-10, 1e-8, 1e-7,1e-6,1e-5,1e-4, 1e-3,1e-2, 1, 5 ,20]
mins=[]
maxs=[]
mean_err=[]
alphas=[]

mins1=[]
maxs1=[]
mean_err1=[]
alphas1=[]

#mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('../../MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
def getdata(percent):
    gsd = GEO.get_GEO(geo="GDS4971")
    ngsd = gsd.table.replace('null', np.NaN)
    ngsd = ngsd.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
    ngsd =ngsd.transpose()
    dataarray = ngsd.values
    data = np.delete(dataarray, [0,1], 0)

    x = data.astype(np.float)
    r_df = x.shape[0]
    c_df = x.shape[1]
    r = int(r_df-math.sqrt((1-percent)*r_df))
    c = int(c_df-math.sqrt((1-percent)*c_df))
    train = x[0:r,:]
    test = x[r:r_df,:]
    return x,train,test,r_df,c_df,r,c


genedata,train,test,r_df,c_df,r,c = getdata(miss_percent)
predictors = range(0,c)

promotion =[[0.001 for x in range(len(alpha_lasso))] for y in range(c_df-c)]
promotion = np.asmatrix(promotion)
#error of ax-b 
error_aw_b = [[0.001 for x in range(len(alpha_lasso))] for y in range(c_df-c)]
error_aw_b = np.asmatrix(error_aw_b)
#error of cw-x
error_cw_x = [[0.001 for x in range(len(alpha_lasso))] for y in range(c_df-c)]
error_cw_x = np.asmatrix(error_cw_x)
#error of lasso function
error_lasso = [[0.001 for x in range(len(alpha_lasso))] for y in range(c_df-c)]
error_lasso = np.asmatrix(error_lasso)

promotion1 =[[0.001 for x in range(len(alpha_lasso))] for y in range(c_df-c)]
promotion1 = np.asmatrix(promotion)
#error of ax-b 
error_aw_b1 = [[0.001 for x in range(len(alpha_lasso))] for y in range(c_df-c)]
error_aw_b1 = np.asmatrix(error_aw_b)
#error of cw-x
error_cw_x1 = [[0.001 for x in range(len(alpha_lasso))] for y in range(c_df-c)]
error_cw_x1 = np.asmatrix(error_cw_x)
#error of lasso function
error_lasso1 = [[0.001 for x in range(len(alpha_lasso))] for y in range(c_df-c)]
error_lasso1 = np.asmatrix(error_lasso)


mybeta = #any initialization

######################              LASSO              #####################
print("#####  lasso model errors  #####")
for j in range(c,c+1):
    mean_err=[]
    print("\n")
    y=j
    eachMeanError= math.sqrt((np.power(errorC[:,j-c],2)).sum()/(r_df-r))
    print("gene: "+str(j)+ " matrix error: "+ str(eachMeanError))
    for i in range(0,4):#len(alpha_lasso)):
        lassoreg = Lasso(alpha=alpha_lasso[i],warm_start=True,tol=0.00000001,max_iter=100000)
        lassoreg.coef_ = mybeta[:,j-c]
        lassoreg.fit(train[:,predictors],train[:,y])
        y_train_pred = lassoreg.predict(A)#train[:,predictors])
        y_test_pred = lassoreg.predict(C)#test[:,predictors])
        y_lasso_func = (1/(2*r))*sum(y_train_pred)+sum(abs(lassoreg.coef_))
        ##################      RMS     ##################
        error_aw_b[j-c,i] = math.sqrt(sum((y_train_pred-train[:,y])**2)/r) 
        error_lasso[j-c,i] = y_lasso_func
        error_cw_x[j-c,i] = math.sqrt(sum((y_test_pred-test[:,y])**2)/(r_df-r)) 

        mins.extend([(error_cw_x.min())])
        maxs.extend([(error_cw_x.max())])

        promotion[j-c,i] = (((eachMeanError-error_cw_x[j-c,i])/eachMeanError)*100)
        print("alpha: "+str(alpha_lasso[i])+ " error_aw_b: "+str(error_aw_b[j-c,i]) + " error_cw_x: " + str(error_cw_x[j-c,i])+" error_lasso: "+str(error_lasso[j-c,i]) + " promotion: " + str(promotion[j-c,i]) )
        print("coef: " + str(lassoreg.coef_[1:10]))

        lassoreg1 = Lasso(alpha=alpha_lasso[i],tol=0.00000001,max_iter=100000)
        lassoreg1.fit(train[:,predictors],train[:,y])
        y_train_pred1 = lassoreg1.predict(A)#train[:,predictors])
        y_test_pred1 = lassoreg1.predict(C)#test[:,predictors])
        y_lasso_func1 = (1/(2*r))*sum(y_train_pred1)+sum(abs(lassoreg1.coef_))
        ##################      RMS     ##################
        error_aw_b1[j-c,i] = math.sqrt(sum((y_train_pred1-train[:,y])**2)/r) 
        error_lasso1[j-c,i] = y_lasso_func1
        error_cw_x1[j-c,i] = math.sqrt(sum((y_test_pred1-test[:,y])**2)/(r_df-r)) 
        mins1.extend([(error_cw_x1.min())])
        maxs1.extend([(error_cw_x1.max())])

        promotion1[j-c,i] = (((eachMeanError-error_cw_x1[j-c,i])/eachMeanError)*100)
        print("alpha: "+str(alpha_lasso[i])+ " error_aw_b: "+str(error_aw_b1[j-c,i]) + " error_cw_x: " + str(error_cw_x1[j-c,i])+" error_lasso: "+str(error_lasso1[j-c,i]) + " promotion: " + str(promotion1[j-c,i]) )
        print("coef: " + str(lassoreg1.coef_[1:10]))
        print("\n")
    print("max promote:")
    print((promotion[j-c,:].max()))

f = open('analyse_col', 'wb')
np.save(f, [promotion,alphas,error_cw_x,mins,maxs])
f.close()

plt.plot(promotion[:,j-c])
plt.ylabel('coef for ')
plt.xlabel('each gene')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got M samples and N features, with `M=950 , N=5000`.

The takeaway here is: **But when p>n, the lasso criterion is not strictly convex, and hence it may not have a unique minimum.** [reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.0313).

This complicates optimization a bit (keep in mind: it's not the simplest of all problems as non-smooth by nature!) and most solvers will be tuned for the other cases.

In your case there is a clear warning and a recommendation: increase the number of iterations! And make sure your *alphas* are not too small. Not sure, how you did init the latter, but if those `1e-15` magnitudes are hand-made, re-think about your problem-formulation!

The warning is enough to not take those solutions as optimized ones (so: *my lasso has different solutions for different inits* is technically not correct; only your approximated solution behaves like that).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your answer and also the paper is so useful. I know that in some cases it did not converge, but in some cases it did. the iterations are 100000. Convergence means the changes of the coefficients which are less than 0.00000001. In cases which it converged, I thought that it should be near the optimum point and we should not see a big difference. I think the problem is the conditions which you mentioned in the first part of your answer.

Comment: The problem is probably not the dimension (p>n), not the algorithm, but bad scaling. You probably did not preprocess your problem or use some very strange params. A simple norm(new_x - old_x) < eps is obviously not that scale-invariant (although that's only part of the stopping-conds) and is depending on the problem nature. But we don't know your prob.

Comment: I actually test the lasso on normalized and un-normalized data, my data is gene expression. In an un-normalized way, the range was between 6 and 14. In the normalized mode, it is between 0 and 1. I completed the post by code. what do you mean by preprocessing? do you mean normalization?

Comment: you were true, I test the lasso in R too, I get the same result with initialization. I also get the alpha which was selected by cross validation and test the lasso in python by that alpha and I get the same error in python too. The problem was the alpha. but I do not understand that why alpha is effecting on the result with initialization?